# How can you see what import fails in an imported module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, portable-applications

I need to make a portable app to put on a device and I want to put only the modules needed so there will not be all the standard modules so I need to see what my app needs, but if that module misses some imports I cannot see that, because it gives an error without being explicit what fails in that module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./packaging.py", line 30, in <module>
    import simplejson
ImportError: No module named simplejson
```

Is there a way to see what import exactly fails in that module?

Comment: uhm, what do you mean? I think the error is very explicit: there is no such module, that you want to import. Besides, stdlib has `json` module in python2.7

Comment: @SilentGhost As I said in the question I moved python to a device but only without the standard lib, I need and I want to take my dependecies one by one, and put there put there only needed module, if that module lacks an import it says like that, I had that happening also with minidom but managed to see what module was missing

Comment: and I'm telling you that you could use module `json` from standard library instead of `simplejson`. In any case, `ImportError` shows you exactly what dependency is - so I don't understand your question.

Comment: @SilentGhost Did you tried this?

Comment: Nothing fails _in that module_. That module is quite simply not found.

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu: `packaging.py` is failing because the `simplejson` module was not found. What more do you want to know?

Comment: I asure you that I move `__init__.py` in there, I did the same with minidom and it worked, but simplejson uses an `.so` and I'm starting to thin that there could be a dependency in it.

Comment: No there is no dependency, import machinery just couldn't find the module.

Comment: @martineau it this the same with the minidom.py because minidom was missing an import as soon I fed that file needed in the import it worked

Comment: @SilentGhost `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py` is there, so  then what is missing then?

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu: sorry, but there's way to little information for me to tell what the problem is. You could try searching for other people experience embedding Python, some of them are listed in the sidebar.

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu: It could be that the string `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` is not in your `sys.path` folder list so it's not being searched when attempts are made to `import` modules or packages.

Comment: @martineau Thanks, that was the case, please put  that as an answer so I can give you accept, +1!

Comment: @Eduard Florinescu: Done. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the string `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` is not in your `sys.path` folder list so it's not being searched when attempts are made to import modules or packages.

Answer (score 2):

The error means, that the import `import simplejson` fails because there is *“[n]o module named simplejson”*. The solution is to simply install [said module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/).

Answer (score 1):

you can catch the exceptions, to know what went wrong and handle them appropriately:

```
try:
   import simplejson
except ImportError:
   print "simplejson module not found"
   #or do something else here, may be install that module
```